# Extract the x values that make the two functions values equal

Tags: functional-analysis, number-theory, multivariable-calculus, problem-solving

I have two  functions for the x variable. I want to extract x values that make the equations equal.

(1)

$${\small F(x)= a + b - a b + c x - b c x + d x - a d x- a e x + a b e x- b f x + a b f x- c d x   + a d e x  + b c f x - a b e f x}$$
(2)
$${\small G(x)=a + b - a b + c x - b c x + d x - a d x - a e x + a b e x - b f x + 
 a b f x - c d x^2 + a d e x^2 + b c f x^2 - a b e f x^2}$$
where $x\in[0,1]$

equal to each other (i.e. F(x)=G(x) )

Is it possible to make a law according to the structure of the  functions

In other words. A law to extract values according to the structure of  functions

I do not know where to start and how to extract values

This is possible for 0 and 1.

Comment: What you wrote are functions of $x\,$, not equations. Assuming you meant $\,=0\,$ for both, the first one is linear in $x\,$. Solve it for $\,x\,$ then substitute into the second one to get the relation between $\,a,b,c,d,e,f\,$ so that the two equations have a common root. By direct subtraction, one sufficient condition is $x(x-1)(cd-ade-bcf+abef)=0\,$.

Comment: @dxiv I do not understand how to do that. Can you answer the way?

Comment: The question is unclear. Do you mean that both expressions have the value zero (i.e. $(1)=0$ and $(2)=0$) or do you mean that they are equal to each other (i.e. $(1)=(2)$ ) ? If you mean $(1)=(2)$ then $x=0$ and $x=1$ are the only solutions.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis equal to each other (i.e. (1)=(2) )

Comment: @Emadkareem See my first comment. If $\,cd-ade-bcf+abef \ne 0\,$ then that implies $\,x(x-1) = 0\,$ i.e. $\,x \in \{0,1\}\,$. Otherwise the two expressions are equal fo all $\,\forall x\,$.

Comment: @dxiv Can you take the value of $x \in [0,1]$ to make the equations equal as an example .

Comment: @dxiv Can you take the an one value of x∈[0,1] to make the equations equal as an example

Comment: @Emadkareem If for example $\,a=b=c=d=e=f=1\,$ then the two expressions are equal for $\,\forall x \in \mathbb{R}\,$. That's just one case of $\,cd-ade-bcf+abef=0\,$, see my previous comments why that matters.

Comment: @dxiv $cd−ade−bcf+abef=0$ factorizes into $(d-bf)(c-ae)=0$, so you need only $d=bf$ or $c=ae$ for it to be true for all $x$.